# @manytomany realación n:m primary key con 3 campos

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Tengo una dos entidades, llamemoslas entidad 1 y entidad 2 que tienen una relación n:m, he creado en la bbdd la tabla de cada entidad y otra tabla que representa la relación n:m de éstas dos. En las entidades 1 y 2 he creado la relacion @manytomany en cada una de ellas para representar esta relación, hasta ahi todo me va bien para acceder a la colección de cada una que está en la otra. No he tenido que generar ninguna entidad en java para representar la relación n:m ya que accedo a los datos a través del set y get de los atributos. Ahora debo agregar a la tabla de la relación (que no es una entidad) un atributo nuevo y cambiar la primary key que estaba compuesta por la primary key de la entidad 1 y 2 añadiendole otro campo, con lo cual ahora la primary key de la relación n:m estará compuesta de las  primarys key de la entidad 1 y 2 más un valor numérico y no se como hacer esto con las anotaciones que tengo en las entidades 1 y 2.

Comment: Busca los annotations Embeddable y  EmbeddedKey. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda  @juan. He revisado el post del link que me pusiste, he pillado la idea. Comentar que tuve que cambiar la relación en la entidad 1 y 2 al tipo del  entidad 3(relación 3) ya que en el ejemplo en la entidad1 la variable generado con la anotacion  `@OneToMany` estaba puesta con la entidad contraria y no me funcionaba porque debe ser de la siguiente manera:         
    `@OneToMany(
     mappedBy = "entidad1",
     cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
     orphanRemoval = true
     )
     private List<entidad3> variable= new ArrayList<>();`